# child div width not 100%, there is some sort of padding on left and right side

Tags: html, css

When the page is loaded with full width there is a black block on the left and right side. I can't figure out what is causing this. I uploaded a screenshot of what it looks like below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid
}

.row1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container border-primary container1">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="col col1" style="background-color: red;">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col2" style="background-color: white; ">
      two of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col col3" style="background-color: green;">
      three of three columns
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your styles are interfering with Bootstraps styles.

Comment: One of the classes you have on the parent div is probably setting some margin/padding. Consider removing those classes or finding where they're set and changing them. It's not in the code you've shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap and default **.container** class have some padding. And also your row class is not 100% width.
So, here is the final code.

```
  .container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its your d-flex thats causing this. Update your css to:

```
.container1 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```